# When __dirname is not absolute?

Tags: node.js

Are there cases when [__dirname](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) is not absolute in `node.js`? Relative, empty or unset.

Comment: Good question! When I try to launch a script as a string from package.json, it render as a simple dot :-/ I'm curious to know why