# nodejs __dirname is a dot when I try to execute a script directly in package.json file

Tags: node.js, package.json, npm-scripts

Here is a chunk of my package.json file:

```
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "run-test": "node -e 'require(`my-test-lib`).whichPath(__dirname )'",
    },
    ...
}
```

When I read my function param into the 'test' script, it is a simple dot `.` :-s

I thought that `__dirname` was always absolute, but it's not the case...

I've used `process.cwd()` for the moment, but I'm curious why this is not working. Have you got a clue ?

While I was searching, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40138862/when-dirname-is-not-absolute) that is related to the subject and I found relevant, but it has no answer.

Comment: The docs describe __dirname to be "The directory name of the current module". Since you're using `-e` flag to execute the code, no module is actually loaded, so it'd make sense not to expect an actual path from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**__dirname**

has a different value depending on which file is invoked it in, whereas.

@laggingreflex mentioned in comments: "The docs describe `__dirname` to be "The directory name of the current module". Since you're using -e flag to execute the code, no module is actually loaded, so it'd make sense not to expect an actual path from it"

**process.cwd()**

always returns the same value, which is the absolute path of where you started the Node.js process (eg., $ node index.js).

```
console.log(__dirname); // /project
console.log(process.cwd()); // /project

const test = require('./module');

/* module code

console.log(__dirname); /project/module
console.log(process.cwd()); /project

*/
```

Comment: Note that you can start your node process from any directory (even a directory in another disk) so `process.cwd()` can vary widely depending on how you start your process

Comment: Agree. as mentioned above in definition.